# UPS getting restarted for every 5 to 10 minutes. What might be reasons and what are remedies?

Tags: motherboard

I have WEP 600VA UPS for my PC. It has 15minutes backup and worked perfect since last 3yrs. But from last 3days its backup time drastically decreased. Its not giving even 5minutes of backup. And without any pop up or notice its getting restarted for every 5 to 10 minutes. restart is occuring after using system for 1 to 2 hrs continously. What shal I do to fix this problem?

Comment: The UPS probably needs a new battery.

Comment: Does the UPS keep the power on if you unplug it from the mains? Is anything other than your PC itself plugged into the UPS' battery backed outlets? Did you change anything recently?

Comment: could be a bad battery - how long does it last without anything connected? - how long does it last with a very low draw appliance connected? - hope this helps.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - *"Does the UPS keep the power on if you unplug it from the mains?"* - Unsafe suggestion!  This can create a hazard of live AC-powered equipment without any grounding.  The safe way to test this is using a power strip between the UPS and the wall outlet; this will maintain a ground connection.

Comment: "*It has 15minutes backup"* -- That's just an marketing estimation based on a small load.  What do you actually have plugged in to its outlets?  *"its backup time drastically decreased"* -- How often are you actually using getting power outages?  Have you plugged in more devices or replaced an inkjet with a laser printer?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your UPS might need a new battery. Three years is not an unreasonable lifetime for a UPS battery.

If your computer is experiencing loss of power *while the UPS is connected to the mains*, the unit might have developed a fault.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my ups have warranty for 3 yrs it completed recently. So its not unreasonable i guess. Do you find any other reason for this problem  ??